# C# COM INTEROP in c++

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I'm trying to call my C# dll from a C++ client, so far I have the dll all setup and in my registry (I can create and call it from the power shell for example).

The problem I'm having is that I can't call it from my C++ code.

My C# interface:

```
namespace MyInterop
{
    [Guid("BE507380-1997-4BC0-AF01-EE5D3D537E6B"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IMyDotNetInterface
    {
        void ShowCOMDialog();
    }
}
```

My C# class that implements the interface:

```
namespace MyInterop
{

    [Guid("38939B1E-461C-4825-80BB-725DC7A88836"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class MyDotNetClass : IMyDotNetInterface
    {
        public MyDotNetClass()
        { }

        public void ShowCOMDialog()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am a" + 
                  "  Managed DotNET C# COM Object Dialog");
        }
    }
}
```

Very simple as I'm just testing at the moment. I now import the tlb into my C++ file

```
#import "<Path to file>\MyInterop.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

Finally I try to call it:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

MyInterop::IMyDotNetInterfacePtr MyDotNetClass(__uuidof(MyInterop::MyDotNetClass));

MyDotNetClass->ShowCOMDialog();

CoUninitialize();
```

But, VS is telling me that ShowCOMDialog is not a member of my interface. Have I missed something?

Comment: Can you remove the ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None) attribute from the class? Not sure it's causing problem, but its at least useless. also, can you remove the raw_interfaces_only attribute?

Comment: As I've been following a tutorial on how to do COM interop, could you explain why the ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None) is useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring `raw_interfaces_only`, you have surpressed the generation of wrapper functions, as indicated in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds25e53.aspx) link. And since your interface is based on `IDispatch`, you are forced to call your interface methods indirectly via IDispatch's [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479(v=vs.85).aspx).

Suggestions:

1. Change your interface type to `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual` or `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown`
2. Remove `raw_interfaces_only` in order to work with the generated wrapper functions.

Comment: I changed my interface type to InterfaceIsIUnknown. This solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear. Note that if you intend to keep `raw_interfaces_only`, you should always check the `HRESULT` return value. It will tell you whether the method succeeded or not.